# Office js Excel add on stuck on white screen after updating code

Tags: office-js

In the `manifest.xml` we define entry points for our task pane add on. This add on points to a url like `https://somedomain.com/taskpane.html` where the add on html+css+js is served.

For some reason whenever the code is updated, the task pane presents a white screen and will not load the add on unless you uninstall and reinstall or if you reload the add on from the add on menu.

Is this by design? If not, is there any way to determine what exactly is causing it?

I've modified the code to show a loading screen until the Office js library is loaded and ready, but the loading screen doesn't even render. This leads me to believe it's something else causing this but I haven't been able to figure out what exactly.

Is anyone else experiencing this?